# Angularjs changing route doesn't load data (ngRepeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

Of course, I should mention that I'm new to this thing, so sorry if this is something trivial.

So I pretty much have 2 routes (views). `localhost:3000` takes in and loads up a list of objects and `localhost:3000/:slug` shows information of the product the users wants to see more info about.

The initial listing is fine. You visit `localhost:3000` and you see a list of items.

listPhoneController.js:

```
angular.module('cmscApp').controller('listPhoneController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'searchBoxFactory',
    function($scope, $http, $location, searchBoxFactory) {
        $scope.listInfo = searchBoxFactory;
        $scope.phoneList = [];

        $http.get('/api/getallphones').then(function(res) {
            $scope.phoneList = res.data;
        }, function() {
            $scope.errorMsg = 'Error in reaching data';
        });
}]);
```

list.html:

```
<!-- ... --->
<div class="result" ng-repeat="phone in phoneList | hasImageFilter:listInfo.imageRequired
                                                  | nameFilter:listInfo.phoneName
                                                  | priceFilter:listInfo.price.from:listInfo.price.to">
    <!-- filters don't seam to be the problem (removing them still causes the issue) -->
    <a ng-href="/phone.slug">More info...</a>
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Now, if I click on the `a` tag, I get redirected to that phone's information view (ie. `localhost:3000/samsung-galaxy-s4`) and information is being loaded correctly. I also have a back button there, with a simple `<a ng-href='/'>Back</a>`

**But**, when I go back, even though the URL changes back to `localhost:3000`, the list doesn't appear. I get no errors, nothing, but the `div`'s aren't there (when inspecting, nor anything).

Is this because `$http` is async, so it tries to load the page before it gets the info? If that's the case, why doesn't it just bind the data, as usual?

Here's my config:

```
angular.module('cmscApp').config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/pages/list.html',
            controller: 'listPhoneController',
            controllerAs: 'lpc'
        })
        .when('/:phoneSlug', {
            templateUrl: '/pages/detail.html',
            controller: 'detailPhoneController',
            controllerAs: 'dpc'
        })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl: '/error/404.html'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
});
```

Any sort of help is more than welcome!! I thought about storing the data from `$http` to a factory, so then it loads that data every time the controller is run, while updating it as well. would that be a viable solution, or is there something better?

Comment: Does rerouting with `<a ng-href='/'>Back</a>` by any chance send you to the `'/:phoneSlug'` route again and call `detailPhoneController` with an undefined phoneSlug by any chance, which hints the problem is with your link/routing?
you can easily test this by logging when controller initializes

Comment: @Sina Gh nope, I tested and routing successfully turns to the listPhoneController (initial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the scope didn't bind for some reason, so I had to edit the `$http.get().then()` method:

```
$http.get(...).then(function(res) { 
    $scope.data = res;
    $scope.$apply();
}, function() { ... });
```

*for anyone encountering a similar issue*